# TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Tags: python

I'm writing my first "real" project, a web crawler, and I don't know how to fix this error.  Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    for page in range(1, max_pages+1):
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll("a"):
            href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + link.get("href")
            print(href)
    page += 1

main_spider(1)
```

Here's the error

```
href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + link.get("href")
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

Comment: did you check if link.get("href") returned a string? your code's not indented properly.

Comment: I am sorry for being so dumb it seems I fixed it but now I have a new problem.  Instead of getting all the links from the page i'm getting the url to the original page over and over again.

Comment: how come? you indented main_spider(1) and you shouldn't get anything. or you had two main_spider(1) lines, one in the function itself?

Comment: @MSeifert okay.  link.get("href") would return None for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @Shiping, your code is not indented properly ... I corrected it below.
Also... `link.get('href')` is not returning a string in one of the cases.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main_spider(max_pages):
    for page in range(1, max_pages+1):
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll("a"): 

            href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + link.get("href")
            print(href)

main_spider(1)
```

For purposes of evaluating what was happening, I added several lines of code...between several of your existing lines AND removed the offending line (for the time being).

```
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        print('All anchor tags:', soup.findAll('a'))     ### ADDED
        for link in soup.findAll("a"): 
            print(type(link.get("href")), link.get("href"))  ### ADDED
```

The result of my additions was this (truncated for brevity):
NOTE: that the first anchor does NOT have an href attribute and thus `link.get('href')` can't return a value, so returns `None`

```
[<a id="top"></a>, <a href="#mw-head">navigation</a>, 
<a href="#p-search">search</a>, 
<a href="/wiki/Special:SiteMatrix" title="Special:SiteMatrix">sister...   
<class 'NoneType'> None
<class 'str'> #mw-head
<class 'str'> #p-search
<class 'str'> /wiki/Special:SiteMatrix
<class 'str'> /wiki/File:Wiktionary-logo-v2.svg      
...
```

To prevent the error, a possible solution would be to add a conditional OR a try/except expression to your code. I'll demo a conditional expression.

```
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll("a"): 
            if link.get('href') == None:
                continue
            else:
                href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + link.get("href")
                print(href)
```

Comment: Great that works perfectly!  However is there a way I could limit the links I get back to only the ones about Star Wars?  Considering that it's set up for every link on the page, could I limit the output to the main links?

Answer (score 1):

The first "a" link on the wikipedia page is

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

Therefore, link.get("href") will return None, as there is no href.

To fix this, check for None first:

```
if link.get('href') is not None:
    href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + link.get("href")
    # do stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all anchors (`<a>` elements) need to have a `href` attribute (see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp):

> In HTML5, the  tag is always a hyperlink, but if it has no href attribute, it is only a placeholder for a hyperlink.

Actually you already got the Exception and Python is great at handling exceptions so why not catch the exception? This style is called ["Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission." (EAFP)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) and is actually encouraged:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main_spider(max_pages):
    for page in range(1, max_pages+1):
        url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll("a"):
            # The following part is new:
            try:
                href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars" + link.get("href")
                print(href)
            except TypeError:
                pass

main_spider(1)
```

Also the `page = 1` and `page += 1` lines can be omitted. The `for page in range(1, max_pages+1):` instruction is already sufficient here.

Comment: @DylanBoyd I updated the answer. I don't know how it could lead to a SyntaxError but maybe something went wrong with indentation or during copy. :)

Comment: I ended up using the answer above with an else statement.  Thanks for you're help

Comment: @DylanBoyd No problem if you choose another answer - but if you want to use a conditional I would recommend [Jackywathys answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43566612/5393381) instead. The `continue` is unnecessary and then you don't need the `else`.

Comment: Oh you're right works great that way as well!  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error from different code. After adding a conditional inside a function, I thought that the return type was not being set properly, but what I realized was that when the condition was False, the return statement was not being called at all -- a change to my indentation fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in a similar situation.

I was concatenating strings too and one variable was supposed to be assigned a return value of a function.

But in one case there was no return value and the variable was "empty". This caused the same error message.

```
input = get_input() # <-- make sure this always returns a value
print ("input was" + input)
```